# Ubuntu 23.04 Installing VM from virt-manager no keyboard when running from within VNC

Tags: keyboard, vnc

I'm running ubuntu 23.04. Vanilla install using iso image of 23.04 to install a VM, the keyboard doesn't seem to work. It all works when i use the native CONSOLE, but not from within a VNC. Tried different viewers and still no luck.

running Xtightvnc  session. The native console is very slow across KVM, but need to get this running on the VNC.

When i type with the keyboard, I can't  see anything.

Comment: could you give some screen shots